# self-closing script tag doesn't really close

Tags: google-chrome, xhtml

I'm developing a small html page on Google Chrome, and I' writing it in XHTML. The beginning the of the document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

"DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xml:lang="en">

  <head>

     <style href="tbx2html.css" type="text/css"/>
```

The `style` tag should be self-closing; however, it doesn't close and the rest of the page is placed inside of it, so that nothing displays. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: You may be writing it in XHTML, but you are serving it as HTML. I recommend reading http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Chrome has added this feature against the standard, that is not how you reference style sheets. Use the `link` tag:

```
<link href="tbx2html.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Fixed it! But why did using a `style` tag that closed itself cause everything to be put inside of it?

Comment: Because the script tag must have content. As @nachito says, running your page through a validator would have told you so.

Comment: @drdwilcox - actually no. The validator would have pointed out the bad `href` attribute, and also the missing `xmlns` attribute, but it would not have required the style (or script) element to have content, or have separate start and end tags.